# Java ResultSet Issue

Tags: java, postgresql

Please refer to the following code, I am just trying to query the DB and get the ResultSet and traverse it:

```
public boolean tokenValidation(ResultSet tokenDetails) {

        try {

            logger.error("INFO" + "|" + new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(new Date()) + "|" +
                new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm").format(new Date()) + "|" + "Service " + "|" +
                "tokenValidation" + "|" + "Validation Token");

            long MILLIS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 L;
            String apiToken = null;
            Timestamp apiTokenTime = null;
            Timestamp currentTime = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());


            if (tokenDetails != null) {
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------Not Null");
            }


            System.out.println(tokenDetails.getClass().toString());
            System.out.println(tokenDetails.getClass());
            while (tokenDetails.next()) {
                System.out.println("111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
                apiToken = tokenDetails.getString("token");
                logger.info(apiToken);
                apiTokenTime = tokenDetails.getTimestamp("date");
                System.out.println("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("exception");

        }
```

But I am facing the following exception, which I never encountered before:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invoked method public abstract boolean java.sql.ResultSet.next() throws java.sql.SQLException is no accessor method
```

I tried to print ResultSet Object class, but I received the following response:

```
class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy197
class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy197
```

I am not sure if the response is correct for ResultSet Class.

I can see the logs till `-----------------------------------Not Null`, then the `getClass()` lines.
The program is throwing exception at `.next()`.

It will be great if someone can help me to understand the issue.

Note: It is a postgres database

Database Properties:

```
#jdbc Connection
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=

spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=
spring.jpa.database = POSTGRESQL 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none 
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

#### Hikari connection pool properties #####
spring.datasource.type = com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=3
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=7

spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

I am calling the `tokenValidation` function in the following code/section:

```
public String token() {
//id = 1234
ResultSet tokenDetails = myRequestRepository.findtoken(id);
        
boolean result = tokenValidation(tokenDetails);

//my other operations
}
```

Repository code:

```
public interface myRequestRepository extends CrudRepository<myProfileRequestModel,Integer> {
    
    @Query(value="select token,date,id from dev_check.token_table\r\n"
            + "lr where lr.id =:id ORDER BY lr.creationdate DESC limit 1",nativeQuery = true)
    ResultSet findtoken(@Param("id")int id);
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>demo.token</groupId>
    <artifactId>token_check</artifactId>
    <version>token_check</version>
    <name>token_check</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.vault/spring-vault-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.vault</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-vault-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>


            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>

            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>

            <version>${gson.version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>

            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>

            <artifactId>jwks-rsa</artifactId>

            <version>0.18.0</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>

            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>

            <version>3.16.0</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>

            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>

            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>

            <version>2.3.1</version>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invoked method public abstract boolean java.sql.ResultSet.next() throws java.sql.SQLException is no accessor method
        at org.springframework.data.projection.Accessor.<init>(Accessor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.MapAccessingMethodInterceptor.invoke(MapAccessingMethodInterceptor.java:60)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectingMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProjectingMethodInterceptor.java:77)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.ProxyProjectionFactory$TargetAwareMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProxyProjectionFactory.java:253)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy197.next(Unknown Source)
        at job.well.my.service.myService.tokenValidation(myService.java:4076)
        at job.well.my.service.myService.companyProfileService(myService.java:786)
        at job.well.my.controller.myController.companyProfile(myController.java:185)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
exception
```

Comment: are you using the correct driver for PostgreSQL?

Comment: This seems like something weird is going on with Spring trying to proxy your `ResultSet` for some reason. Can you show us how you call that method? (Ideally all the way down to how you create/get that `ResultSet`)? *Are you* using Spring at all in your program?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Added my Database properties details in the question.

Comment: @Reimeus Added my Database properties details in the question.

Comment: That's ... not what I asked for ... I asked for the code that *calls* this method.

Comment: Please add your dependencies. Feels like you are using some ancient version of the postgres driver. Also please add the **full stacktrace** and not just a snippet.

Comment: @JoachimSauer added the remaining information

Comment: @M.Deinum Added additional details

Comment: Why are you returning `ResultSet` from a repository method. It will be interpreted as a projection and not as a `ResultSet`. If you need direct access tot the resultset use the `JdbcTemplate` but not as a return type from a Spring Data repository method. Or use a proper projection and return a list of that projection.

Comment: Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next() Check if you are receiving a ResultSet that has been closed or the underlying connection has been closed.

Comment: Can you please add the definition of the '@Entity' myProfileRequestModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a `ResultSet` back from a `CrudRepository<myProfileRequestModel,Integer>`.

Change your repo defn to the following:

```
public interface myRequestRepository extends CrudRepository<myProfileRequestModel,Integer> {
        
        @Query(value="select token,date,id from dev_check.token_table\r\n"
                + "lr where lr.id =:id ORDER BY lr.creationdate DESC limit 1",nativeQuery = true)
        Optional<myProfileRequestModel> findtoken(@Param("id")int id);
}
```

And access the token as follows:

```
        Optional<myProfileRequestModel> tokenDetailsOptional = myRequestRepository.findtoken(id);
        if(tokenDetailsOptional.isPresent()) {
            myProfileRequestModel myProfileRequestModel = tokenDetailsOptional.get();
            String token = myProfileRequestModel.token;
            Timestamp date = myProfileRequestModel.date;
        }
```

I am assuming that myProfileRequestModel looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class myProfileRequestModel {
    
    @Id
    int id;
    
    Timestamp date;
    
    String token;
    

}
```

Comment: Thanks I changed the response type to Model and it worked.